# C# Reflection get the instance behind FieldInfo

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, system.reflection

I am having an issue with Reflection, which I can't seem to find a solution for.

I have the following simple interface :

```
    public interface IDataProperty<T> 
{
   public T Value { get; set; } 
   public int BytesCount();
   public byte[] Serialize();
}
```

the struct which implements the interface above :

```
    public struct IntProperty : IDataPropery<int> 
{
    private int _value; 
    public int Value { get => _value; set => _value = value; }

    public int BytesCount()
    {
        return 4;
    }

    public byte[] Serialize()
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(_value);
    }
    public IntDataProperty(int value) { _value = value; }
}
```

and a simple class to hold the values :

```
public class ValuesContainer  
{
   public IntProperty prop1;
   public IntProperty prop2;
}
```

I am trying to call the `Serialize()` method on both `prop1` and `prop2` in my Processor class,
with no luck so far... :

```
public class Processor  
{
   public void ProccesData<T>(out T result) where T : ValuesContainer, new() 
    {
      result = new T();
        List<FieldInfo> dataFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
        result.GetType().GetFields().ToList().ForEach(field => { 
        if(field.FieldType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDataProperty<>)))
            {
                dataFields.Add(field);
            }
              });
         MethodInfo serializeMI = typeof(IDataProperty<>).GetMethod("Serialize");
         foreach(FieldInfo field in dataFields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
            serializeMI.Invoke(field,null);
        }

    }
}
```

Running the code at this point gives me the following error :

```
'Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.'
```

I am aware that I need to get somehow to the instance behind the `field` variable, but have no idea how to do it.
Does anyone know a good way of doing what i am trying to achieve using other methods, or only Reflection is the way to go, and if the latter - what solutions do I have ?

Thanks in advance to all of you.

Comment: This makes little sense as written. What are you expecting to serialize? You are explicitly creating a new `T` yourself, so the only values you'll be getting that way are defaults. Of course if you really want to you can get at those: `field.GetValue(result)` (and that's the object you want to be calling `Serialize` on). As an aside -- calling fields "properties" is needlessly misleading. You probably want to make them properties in any case.

Comment: `Type.GetFields` returns only public fields when called with no arguments. If I understand your issue correctly, you are trying to access the `_value` field, which is private.

Comment: @JackA. I am trying to invoke the Serialize() method in my Processor.ProcessData function on each of the ValuesContainer instance's fields.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the answer. Tried `field.GetValue(result)` and still getting the same error. Actually Serialize() is just an example function . as well as all the class names , field names, etc. This is just for reproduction of the code .

Comment: You will keep getting that error as long as you keep using `typeof(IDataProperty<>).GetMethod("Serialize")`, as you cannot invoke methods from open generics. But when you have the object of `field.GetValue(result)` you can just use `.GetType().GetMethod()` on that. (It *is* possible to get the method of `IDataProperty<...>` specifically in case the call is ambiguous, but that's a lot more work -- having a non-generic `IDataProperty` for a base type that contains the `Serialize` method would greatly simplify that.)

Comment: The idea behind this is , that I want to give the consumers of my code easy way to create own `IDataProperty<>` implementations , but the code behind the processing needs to call the so called `Serialize()` function for each implementation on each `IDataProperty<>` in a given `ValuesContainer` or any class containing `IDataProperty<>`

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks. Still, the `MethodInfo.Invoke()` requires an `object` parameter and if I use `result ` I get ` Object doesn't match error` , because it is just a `ValuesContainer ` instance... the whole purpose of this question is what to put as the `object` parameter in the `Ivoke()` method :) .

Comment: The result of `field.GetValue(result)`, obviously, same as where you can get the type from. You need to invoke the method on the instance of the field, not `ValuesContainer`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are a lifesaver !!!! If you put this as an answer I will mark it as accepted . Thanks so much for helping my burnt out brain to see through hahah :P !

Answer (score 0):

After the great help @JeroenMostert provided in the comments , i have been able to solve the issue at its roots. As long as Jeroen haven't provided an answer to be accepted as correct , I will just show his solution , so this question gets marked as answered. Still, the benefit here goes to @JeroenMostert

```
    internal class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ValuesContainer container = new ValuesContainer();
            Processor processor = new Processor();
            processor.ProccesData(out container);
        }
     }
    public interface IDataProperty<T>
    {
        public void Serialize();
    }
    public struct IntProperty : IDataProperty<int>
    {
        private int _value;
        public int Value { get => _value; set => _value = value; }

        public int BytesCount()
        {
            return 4;
        }

        public void Serialize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I have been invoked !" + this.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
    public class ValuesContainer
    {
        public IntProperty prop1;
        public IntProperty prop2;
    }
    public class Processor
    {
        public void ProccesData<T>(out T result) where T : ValuesContainer, new()
        {
            result = new T();
            List<FieldInfo> dataFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
            result.GetType().GetFields().ToList().ForEach(field => {
                if (field.FieldType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDataProperty<>)))
                {
                    dataFields.Add(field);
                }
            });         
            foreach (FieldInfo field in dataFields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invoking 'Serialize' method on fieldName :" + field.Name);
              field.GetValue(result).GetType().GetMethod("Serialize").Invoke(field.GetValue(result), null);          
            }
        }
    }
```